# Makefile error (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: makefile

I'm completely new to Makefile (and to Docker), and I'm struggling with understanding how to point to a subdirectory.

This is the file structure:

```
project
[...docker
[   [...Dockerfile
[
[...client
[   [...docker
[       [...Dockerfile
[...api

(Sorry, can't find the pipe on my keyboard)
```

The Makefile includes two builds.

```
# Makefile
build_api:
    @ docker compose build

build_client:
    @ client/docker compose build

up: build_api build_client
    @ docker compose up -d
```

The api image gets created and launched, but the client image fails with this error:

```
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:5: build_client] Error 2
```

**How can I point to a subdirectory inside the Makefile?**

Comment: The format of build_client is trying to run the client/docker folder as a command. Try `@ cd client ; docker compose build` instead. This should then enter the client folder and then run docker there.

Comment: @MOStudios `@ cd client;` worked, thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your Makefile as of now is set up to try to run the folder `client/docker` as a command.

Instead, try `@ cd client ; docker compose build`

This should then enter the client folder and then run the docker command there.